# watir - browser.select_list not returining dynamic content

Tags: ruby, watir

I have a drop down box that when a value is selected should dynamically show a second drop down box.

my code works to the point where it selects the value from the 1st drop down but the 2nd drop down remains hidden

here is my code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'www.somesite.com/'
browser.select_List(:class, 'class name').set ('value')
```

Thanks for the quick reply
I have tried ('onchance') and ('onclick')
example:

```
    browser.select_list(:class, 'my class').set ('my value')
    browser.select_list(:class, 'my class').fire_event ('onclick')
```

Here is what is showing on the page

```
    <div class="mydiv"><span class="RqTxt">*</span>Test<div class="clearLine"></div>
    <input name="Name[0][promo]" type="hidden" class="promo" />
    <input name="Name[0][Type]" type="hidden" class="Type" value="1" />
    <span class="HiddenText">*</span>
    <select  name="Name[0][Location_Housing]" class="LocationHousing" >
    <option value="">Please Choose...</option>
    <option value="01">value01</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="Check" >
    <div class="Ckdiv"><span class="RqTxt">*</span>Type<div class="clearLine"></div>
    <span class="HiddenText">*</span>
    <select  name="Name[0][option]"  class="option">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Please Choose...</option>
    <option value="02">value02</option>
    <option value="06">value06</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: could you please share the web page or web page source code so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Make sure you used "onchange" instead of "onchance".  I'm assuming that's just a typo here, but you never know :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, if that does not work, you need to share the HTML from that portion of the page with us

```
browser.select_List(:class, 'class name').fire_event('onchange')
```